# Plotting an ode solution when clicking on the axes

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to write some code that will allow me to click on the axes and the ode solution with the clicked point as the initial condition will be plotted. Here is what I have tried thus far:

```
function myui

clc
close all

xmin=2;
xmax=10;
ymin=-4;
ymax=4;

f=@(t,y) y^2-t

fig=figure;

ax=axes('Units','pixels',...
    'XLim',[xmin,xmax],...
    'YLim',[ymin,ymax],...
    'ButtonDownFcn',@plotode)

    function plotode(source,event)
        initcond=get(ax,'CurrentPoint');
        initcond=initcond(1,1:2)
        [t,y]=ode45(f,[initcond(1),xmax],initcond(2));
        plot(t,y)
        hold on
        [t,y]=ode45(f,[initcond(1),xmin],initcond(2));
        plot(t,y)
        axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax])
        hold off     
    end    

end
```

I have several questions.

1. I can only click one time. I'd like to click several times and draw several curves.
2. The curve can shoot to plus or minus infinity quite quickly, so I'd like to halt ode 45 if it leaves my axes window.

I'd appreciate it if someone could share some complete code that works as I could really learn quite a bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All,

I've added some steps to my code that performs the task I wished to see.

```
function myui

% clear command window and close all open figures
clc
close all

% define our function
f=@(t,y) y^2-t;

% axes boundaries
tmin=2;
tmax=10;
ymin=-4;
ymax=4;

% steps for quiver
tstep=20;
ystep=20;

% create a figure window
fig=figure;

% create axes with limits
ax=axes('Units','Normalized',...
    'XLim',[tmin,tmax],...
    'YLim',[ymin,ymax]);

% create direction field with quiver
[T,Y]=meshgrid(linspace(tmin,tmax,tstep),...
    linspace(ymin,ymax,ystep));
S=Y.^2-T;
L=sqrt(1+S.^2);
quiver(T,Y,1./L,S./L,0.5,'r','ButtonDownFcn',@plotode)
axis tight
hold on

% set ButtonDownFcn on axes ax
set(ax,'ButtonDownFcn',@plotode);

% function plots initial conditions and solutions
    function plotode(source,event)
        warning('off','MATLAB:ode45:IntegrationTolNotMet');
        initcond=get(ax,'CurrentPoint');
        initcond=initcond(1,1:2);
        [t,y]=ode45(f,[initcond(1),tmax],initcond(2));
        plot(t,y,'b','linewidth',1)
        [t,y]=ode45(f,[initcond(1),tmin],initcond(2));
        plot(t,y,'b','linewidth',1)
        plot(initcond(1),initcond(2),'ro')
        set(ax,'XLim',[tmin,tmax],'YLim',[ymin,ymax],...
            'ButtonDownFcn',@plotode);
    end    

end
```

It produces this image when I click on the axes with my mouse several times.

[image]

I'd still love to listen to some instruction and suggestions.

Thanks.